# How to disable verification for some user in Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Amazon Cognito sends verification code automatically if verification feature activated. In my project, sometimes, I will add users(Signup function in AWS Java SDK) and verify them by AdminConfirmSignup myself, so I do not want them to receive verification mail. I will send them customized email manually.(Not using custom lambda in cognito)

If I write pre-signup lambda function and verify the user at that stage, do they still get a verification email?

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using `pre-signup` Lambda trigger you can auto-confirm the user. In this case they will not get a confirmation email. You can find the pre-signup example with auto confirm in [this docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html).

Basically, you set the `autoConfirmUser` flag to true in the event response.

Answer (score 16):

There's faster way to do this without implementing triggers. I spent a lot of time searching this solution, in witch the documentation isnt clear.

Just follow the 2 step tutorial below, with boto3 functions from AWS( https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html# )

1. Create the user with `admin_create_user` function with parameter `MessageAction='SUPPRESS'`

**function details**: this will create a user without confirmation email, with temporary password and **still unconfirmed**

2. Set this new user with permanent password, using `admin_set_user_password` function with parameter `Permanent=True`

**function details**: this function will set the user password as permanent and **auto-confirm the user**

**Extra details**:
I tryed to auto-confirm using the `confirm_sign_up` and `admin_confirm_sign_up` functions, both didnt worked. `admin_confirm_sign_up` just works with users created by `sign_up` function, not by with `admin_create_user`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer. 1-line codified solution as opposed to other infrastructure setup. In our use case, we just needed to disable the default dodgy-looking "temporary password" email so just the `MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS'` was enough. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ive use SignUp but that was only with verification mail. Thank you that should be the accepted answer

Comment: Helpful! Thank you.

Worth noting that this requires administrative IAM credentials.  And if you previously were using the `set_cognito_user_confirmed_status` after creating an account you will need to drop that or get error for trying to confirm an already confirmed user.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, a user may sign up with an email address initially and then later on we add a phone number to their profile. The user pool is setup to either allow a profile to use their email or phone number as a username, but not both. Because of that restriction, I prefer to keep the phone number unverified in Cognito so we know that phone number is not what they use to login with (since Cognito has no good built in way to tell this out-of-the-box).

I verify the phone number outside of Cognito and, once verified, we run `adminUpdateUserAttributes` to set the new phone number. Cognito was sending an additional verification SMS to the phone number. In order to prevent this, I pass in both the `phone_number` attribute and the `phone_number_verified` attribute set to true. Then I make another call to  `adminUpdateUserAttributes` and set `phone_number_verified` back to false. This allows us to have phone number unverified in Cognito and prevents an additional confirmation message from being sent.